# UnauthorizedAccessException with custom dll in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing a web application using Asp.Net Mvc, which uses a custom dll (c#) that writes/reads files. When I run everything I get this error:

```
'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll'
System.TypeInitializationException' in LemRemoteCsh22.dll'
```

How can I solve the problem?